# calling for Domain Login with no domain server

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

I have a stand alone Windows 7 Dynics computer that tells me mu domain login has expired and needs to be changed.  I have no domain so it can not authenticate a password.  How do I tell it I want to login to the local computer?  As I recall XP had an icon on the lower right side of the login screen to change users, this computer has no such icon displayed.

Thank You for any help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force a local logon, you can preface your username with `.\`

For example:

Username: `.\richard`

The `.` is just a shortcut for your local computername, so you could also logon locally using `MYPC\richard`, assuming your PC name is "MYPC".